# Show 30px high JPanel, then fill rest of space with minecraft

Tags: java, swing, minecraft, gridbaglayout, thread-sleep

I am trying to make a JFrame with a 30px JPanel at the top, then add the Minecraft Applet underneath, Both need to resize automatically, I am trying to achieve this with a GridBagLayout, so far I have:

```
public void start(Applet mcApplet, String user, String session) throws MalformedURLException {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    Thread animation = new Thread();
    Dimension size = new Dimension(900, 540);

            JPanel basic = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            basic.setPreferredSize(size);
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            // ADD MINEBOOK MENU
            JLabel menu = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL("http://modpacks.minebook.co.uk/images/menu.png")));

    if(!animationname.equalsIgnoreCase("empty")) {
        try {
            animation.start();
            label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(animationname));
            label.setBounds(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
            fixSize(size);
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
            add(label);
            animation.sleep(3000);
            animation.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            label.add(label);
        } finally {
            remove(label);
        }
    }

    try {
                appletWrap = new Launcher(mcApplet, new URL("http://www.minecraft.net/game"));
    } catch (MalformedURLException ignored) { }
    appletWrap.setParameter("username", user);
    appletWrap.setParameter("sessionid", session);
    appletWrap.setParameter("stand-alone", "true");
    mcApplet.setStub(appletWrap);
            mcApplet.setPreferredSize(size);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.ipady = 30;
            basic.add(menu, c);

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.ipady = 0;
            basic.add(appletWrap, c);

            add(basic);

            pack();
    validate();
    appletWrap.init();
    appletWrap.start();
    fixSize(size);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Try setting weighty to 1.0 (i.e. use up 100% extra space) (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#weighty) Also try using a different GridBagConstraint for each component. One for menu and another for appletWrap. The appletWraps constraint should have the weighty set to 1.0.

Comment: That sort of works, but the minecraft frame is being stretched to 4000px wide, because the menu.png is 4000px, how can I prevent this?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at the `BorderLayout` behaviour for the north panel, but perhaps a `BorderLayout` would be more appropriate - with your 30px panel in the north position, and the applet in the centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use a [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), and place your 30px panel in the `NORTH` position, while your Minecraft applet in the `CENTER` position.